# Table with hierarchy to multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I have a table of company units:

```
Id    Name       Parent
1     Head       null
2     IT dep     1
3     Backoffice 1
4     Devs       2
```

and users

```
Id    Name       UnitId
1     One        1
2     Two        etc
```

Each user has (in other table) some numbers associated, lets call it rating.

I want to create a query which could produce the following report, where `avg rating` is average rating of all users directly in this unit and in subunits, plus user own rating.

```
Unit                                     Avg Rating

Head                                     25%
      IT Dep                             30%
             Devs                        40%
                  Dev1                   50%
                  Dev2                   30%
             SomeoneElse                 20% 
      Backoffice                         35%
             SomeoneInBO                 45%
             AlsoInBO                    25%
```

The approach I'd like to use is to select the same values in nested rows, than send this data to pivot (it will handle displaying this data). So I need result like this

```
Unit  Unit1  Unit2 Who                       Avg Rating

Head  null   null  null                      25%
Head  IT Dep null  null                      30%
Head  IT Dep Devs  null                      40%
Head  IT Dep Devs  Dev1                      50%
Head  IT Dep Devs  Dev2                      30%
etc...
```

I think I've figured out how to do this, if the level of hierarchy is already known, but how to achieve this in general case?

Comment: Check out recursive common table expressions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: I used that =) This is what I did for 3 levels: https://gist.github.com/Rulikkk/ddb5feb67ad3e47655d9
You need two queries for each level: one with users at that level and one for totals at that level

After that I'll add totals along lines of `select avg(rating) from user_rating where user_id in (select all id of users in this and suborgs)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited the previous comment =)

Comment: It's better to include the code you have into your question than to link to an external site

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's really huge code, and more like a workaround, rather than a solution.